# Android: implement search in appbar

Tags: java, android, search, android-animation, search-box

In my application I have an app bar like the one in the image below

[image: app bar example]
<sub>(source: [jayway.com](http://www.jayway.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/first_result.png))</sub>

On the left of the appbar I have a `TextView` and on the right a `SearchView` and a menu.

**How can I implement the search action?**

I would like the searchview expanding to the entire width of the app bar and hiding the `TextView` on the left, when search icon is pressed.
Something like Youtube or Gmail apps.

please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item (add it in res/menu/menu.xml):

```
    <menu>
<!-- ... ->    
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
              android:title="@string/search_title"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
              android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
              android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
    </menu>
```

don't  forget to override

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem menuItemSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) 
        MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItemSearch);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry where I have to add this?

Comment: thx, it works. But if I would use android.support.v7.widget.SearchView  instead of android.widget.SearchView  how can I implement the java onCreateOptionsMenu() ?     Because this code not worws for android.support.v7.widget.SearchView ...

Comment: Did you link the support v7 in gradle?